# Countif and Sumif in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, count, sum

I'm coming to you with a problem related to my Access database.

To keep it simple, I have two tables, `Products` and `Customers` :

[image: Products table]

[image: Customers table]

Those tables come from a simple Excel file I created to keep track of sales.

In this file, the fields `ItemCount` and `TotalBill` from the `Customers` table are calculated fields using `countif` and `sumif` as follows :

```
ItemCount : =COUNTIF(Products[Customer],[@Customer])

TotalBill : =SUMIF(Products[Customer],[@Customer],Products[Price])
```

I've realised with despair that MS Access don't offer those functions in the calculated fields, but there must be a way to do something so basic.

The tables must be kept separated.

If someone could help me to the way I'd be most grateful

Thank you all for reading !

Comment: Don't confuse Excel (spreadsheet program) and Access (database program).

Comment: `DCount()` and `DSum()` will server your purpose.

Comment: Do you want to update second table with count and sum value?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a join and aggregation:

```
select
    c.customerid,
    c.customer,
    count(*) itemcount,
    sum(p.price) totalbill
from products p
inner join customer c on c.customer = p.customer
group by c.customerid, c.customer
```

Note that you shouldn't be using the name of the customer to relate the two tables, but instead the customer id, which, presumably, is the primary key of the customers table.

Comment: Given that the OP has zero values, an outer join might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You do not mention either you just want the result or you want to update `Customers` table columns with calculated value. So, if you want to display all the customer form `customers` table even if there is no transactions on `Products` table then use below query

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerID, Customers.Customer, P.Cnt AS ItemCount, P.Sm AS TotalBill
FROM (SELECT products.customer AS PC, Count(Products.Product) AS Cnt, Sum(Products.Price) AS Sm FROM Products GROUP BY Products.Customer)  AS P 
RIGHT JOIN Customers ON P.PC = Customers.Customer;
```

> Although `MS-Access` discourage to store calculated value to tables [Run queries or report as need] but you can do that if you want. So, to update `Customers` table with values from `Products` table you can try below `UPDATE` query.

```
UPDATE Customers SET Customers.ItemCount = 
DCount("Product","Products","Customer= '" & Customers.Customer & "'"), Customers.TotalBill = 
DSum("Price","Products","Customer= '" & [Customers].[Customer] & "'");
```

[image]